# Is there any way to connect MSSQL server in PHP without installing any extension

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, php-5.4

I am trying to connect MSSQL server database on different server using `PHP (5.4.45)`. I already know about `sqlsrv_connect()` and `odbc_connect()` and tried them. But we cannot use them without installing their extensions and enabling them in `php.ini` file. I wonder is there any way to establish connection with MSSQL server without installing/enabling any extension. As i do not have PHP server access and client has refused to provide the same.

Any one can help?

Comment: Technically you could make a TCP connection and implement Tabular Data Stream yourself...

Answer (score 0):

nope. not possible without installing an extension.